# COUNTIF Year equals Year - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to know how many times a a specific year is found in a column. Format of column C is Date (for example: 15/2/2021). Obviously the code below doesn't work, but to give you an idea:

[image: Example]

In the example above the output on B:1 should be: 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(YEAR(C:C); A1))
```

[image]

---

or get whole table with:

```
=QUERY(C:C; 
 "select year(C),count(C) 
  where C is not null 
  group by year(C) 
  label year(C)'',count(C)''")
```

[image]

Comment: nice approaches, one simple and one advanced and both totally different from the other answer. altough the first answer seems to be the most recommended, it is good to know some powers available with the second. upvoted.

Comment: Thnx again mate! I've learn something again although INDEX and QUERY is something new to me which I will dive in soon :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this workaround:

cell `B1` formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&A1&"-01-01",C:C,"<"&(A1+1)&"-01-01")
```

And then apply the same formula for the rest of column `B` cells.

It will count everything which is greater than or equal to the first day of the year and lower than the first day of next year. It is not pretty but it works.

Comment: Thnx for a not so pretty solution! ;) I sure learn from it